# https not working for 127.0.0.1/localhost but working for IP/DNS

Tags: https, iis-7.5, localhost

I am running IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit).
I got a web application running in the default web site (only got that site)
I have installed an SSL certificate on this web site.
I can see that when accessing the application on either server external IP or DNS the https is working just fine. Both from external access and internal access.

When I access the application from internally and use hostname, localhost or 127.0.0.1 I get the standard IE error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" which is normal circumstances would suggest that https is not running.
I can telnet 127.0.0.1 443 just fine.

Comment: The error message indicates your problem is not IIS, but probably some firewall or antivirus blocking software setting.

Comment: I found that when I map localhost in my hosts file to the server IP it works as well. So basically I have avoided the issue, but I am still puzzled why it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Does https 127.0.0.1 works? Instead of just using http only.